# List of generally believed conjectures which cannot all be true

Tags: soft-question, conjectures

There are some conjectures which most leading experts believe in albeit no one can prove it yet. For example: $\mathcal{P} \neq \mathcal{NP}$, the Riemann hypothesis or the Collatz conjecture.

My question is whether there is a set of such conjectures which cannot all be true, eg. is a statement such as "Either $\mathcal{P} = \mathcal{NP}$ or the Riemann hypothesis is wrong" true?

Answer (score 29):

In an early instance of a [computer-assisted proof](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183535510), [Douglas Hensley](http://www.math.tamu.edu/people/formalpg.php?user=dhensley) and Ian Richards (*Primes in Intervals*, Acta Arithmetica 25 (1974), 375-391) proved that two conjectures of [Hardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._H._Hardy) and [Littlewood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Edensor_Littlewood) about prime numbers, [the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture) (the prime
$k$-tuples conjecture, a generalization of the [twin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) conjecture) and [the second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) (that $\pi(x+y)\le\pi(x)+\pi(y)$), can not both be true. As a result of this work of Hensley and Richards, the second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture has fallen out of favor.

Comment: I love answers where half the text is blue.

Comment: I love comments with a brown-red number in front.