# Conflicting conjectures

Tags: big-list, conjectures

I feel like when two conjectures are inconsistent with one another, it's a clear sign of our misunderstanding of deeper mathematics.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a comprehensive list of conjectures that contradict other conjectures.

Comment: How can there possibly be a comprehensive list of conjectures? It is a difficult judgment whether a conjecture is worth paying any attention to. Any first year undergraduate can come up with hundreds of questions to which we do not know the answer. But few of them would be dignified as "conjectures".

Comment: Perhaps you are familiar with Ian Richards (1974) demonstration that [Hardy and Littlewood's first (k-tuple) conjecture is inconsistent with their second conjecture](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183535510) concerning [prime counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture)?

Comment: @hardmath As stated in the report by Ian Richards that you linked to, the incompatibility of the two Hardy–Littlewood conjectures is the result of ***joint work*** with Douglas Hensley. The main paper is Douglas Hensley and Ian Richards, "Primes in Intervals", Acta Arithmetica 25 (1974), 375-391. (The Hensley–Richard result is to date the only proposed answer to [the previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092480/list-of-generally-believed-conjectures-which-cannot-all-be-true) about conflicting conjectures.)

Comment: @bof: Yes, not the biggest of lists (but highly upvoted, at any rate).